# How to simultaneously update multiple object's values inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm trying to simultaneously update 2 object's values inside an array when an onClick function is called. Currently I am able to decrement the target (selected) value by 1 (e.g -1) but am in need of suggestions for my next expectation:

If a previous value exists (e.g an option is selected) and I select a different option (radio button) I expect the previous value to increment by 1 (+1) simultaneously to the new value being decremented.

Array Structure:

```
`(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: 'Space pod', total_no: 2, max_distance: 200, speed: 2}
1: {name: 'Space rocket', total_no: 1, max_distance: 300, speed: 4}
2: {name: 'Space shuttle', total_no: 1, max_distance: 400, speed: 5}
3: {name: 'Space ship', total_no: 2, max_distance: 600, speed: 10}`
```

Current:

```
const handleVehiceChange = (e) => {
setValue(e.target.value);
setVehiclesData(
  vehiclesData.map((vehicle) =>
    vehicle.name === e.target.value
      ? { ...vehicle, total_no: vehicle.total_no - 1 }
      : vehicle
  )
)};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than overwriting the previous state with new state with a decremented `total_no`, I'd have a function that calculates the decremented result *without* putting the result into state. This makes it easy to switch between selected names to decrement.

```
const handleVehiceChange = (e) => {
  setValue(e.target.value);
};
const makeMergedData = () => vehiclesData.map((vehicle) =>
  vehicle.name === value // from state
    ? { ...vehicle, total_no: vehicle.total_no - 1 }
    : vehicle
);
```

Then replace consumers of `vehiclesData` with `makeMergedData()`.

If the `vehiclesData` isn't being changed anywhere else, this might let you remove it from state completely.

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance! It took me a little while to fully understand whether I was needing to update the state itself or whether I could display an updated value without needing to directly update the state itself as you pointed out but this works perfectly.

Comment: I've discovered that I need to render 4 different instances of the updated vehiclesData table and unfortunately this only amends the individual instance of each table. E.g it shows the reduced value for planet x but when rendering the same table/radio options + values for planet y the results are not updated and are set to their initial value - any pointers?

Comment: Make sure to call `makeMergedData()` every time you're using the data - don't use the original `vehiclesData` anymore, or you'll get the original unmodified values.